# Using the path to an .xcconfig file in a configuration setting

Tags: xcode, macos, configuration, settings

I want to use an .xcconfig file to load some predefined settings for my project, mostly libraries with whom I want to link, additional linker paths and header search paths. I'm looking for a solution where I can use the path of the xcconfig file and add relative paths from there.

So something like:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=$(CURRENT_PATH)/../includes/
```

where `$(CURRENT_PATH)` is the path to the xcconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

The path to .xcconfig file is not exposed as a configuration setting. Doing so wouldn't fit with the current evaluation model of Xcode configuration settings.